# При блокировке в Ubuntu автоматически гаснет экран, как это отключить?

Tags: ubuntu

Пользуюсь Ubuntu 14.04. При блокировке юзера комбинацией Ctrl + Alt + L появляется окно с запросом пароля, а затем через некоторое время монитор гаснет. В настройках монитора вроде ничего нет, в настройках Убунты везде, где было можно гашение экрана и переход в спящий режим отключил. Как можно сделать так, чтобы был экран блокировки, но монитор не гас?

Comment: Причём есть забавная фича: если во время гашения экрана дёрнуть мышкой, то он остаётся включённым дольше. В чём вообще логика такого поведения?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте внести настройки в систему по [этой инструкции](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/configure-ubuntu-to-not-dim-or-turn-off-an-inactive-display/) (до установки screensaver-а).

Comment: Уже, всё было внесено сразу после установки системы некоторое время назад. В статье упоминается gnome-screensaver, вот попробовал ещё выполнить gnome-screensaver-command --exit, и нифига, не вырубается эта шняга.